# What is the nominal form of the verb "to give"?

Tags: verbs, morphology, derivational-morphology, derivation, nominalizations

Normally one can add -tion or -ation to a verb to make it nominal, but that nominalization doesn't work for "give". Is there a nominalized form of "to give"? If not, is there a word that could serve the same purpose?

In other words, what word means "the act of giving"?

Comment: Why would _giving_ (the process), _giver_, and _gift_ (that which is given) not suffice?

Comment: Giving seems to refer to the concept ("giving is the spirit of Christmas"), while the nominal form refers to a specific occurrence of the verb. For example: "nominalization" versus "nominilizing".

Comment: There is no real difference in that respect between the gerund and derived nouns in _-ation_; compare _apply -> applying/application_, where the latter can either be the general concept (“the application of lotion/applying lotion to dry skin is important” = “applying oil to dry skin is important”) or a specific instance of it (“I’m trying to convince them through applying/application to their nobler self”). The same is true of _giving_ (“the giving of presents is a common Yuletide tradition” vs. “before the turkey, a hearftelt giving of thanks is expected”).

Comment: Suppose we're using the word without sentencial context. -ing implies the gerund sense before any other, where as -tion implies the nominal form before any other. While they are interchangeable in some circumstances, they have different "priorities" of meaning.

Comment: Then there is no such word. _Giving_ fills both functions for this verb. You’ll have to see if you can find a different verb that has a derived abstract noun (such as _donate_ -> _donation_, for example) if you want to be absolutely sure no gerundial meaning is possible. Note, however, that _-ation_ nouns often share with _gift_ the property that they (can) refer to what is the object of a verbal form, rather than the act of [verb]ing itself. A _donation_ is a kind of _gift_, for example, and a _sensation_ is the thing that you sense.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the related *gifting* might be preferred, but that has another more usual sense.

You're right; there does seem a lack of an ideal noun here.

'Donation' (sense (1) below) works (as Janus suggests it might):

> **donation**
>
> noun
>
> 1. an act or instance of presenting something as a gift, grant, or contribution.
> 2. a gift, as to a fund; contribution.

{[Dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/donation)}, but again, the normal sense (2) is what people would expect (I don't know *why* it's listed second here).

But note that [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/donation), for instance, does not seem to include the 'one-off action' sense:

> 1. The act [I assume practice] of giving to a fund or cause.
> 2. A gift or grant.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a nominalized form of "to give"?

There are three; *give*, *gift* and completely separately, *give*.

Of the sense of the verb meaning "to transfer to another person, to donate" we have the noun *give* referring to the actual thing donated from Old English until around the early 14th century then dying out. We also have it used for the act of giving from the late 13th until the early 14th:

The spellings *ȝefe*, *ȝiftes* and *yeue* are found for this sense.

But then that died out with *gift* becoming the form used for the act of giving (as well as for the thing given, in which use it is currently much more common). This continued into use until the 19th century:

> Language always makes gift of its best wealth to a great poet. — Henry Reed, *Lectures on English literature*, a1854.
>
> Wouldn't have'em at a gift. — Thomas Hughes, *Tom Brown's school days*, 1857

The idiom "in one's gift" used this sense of the word to mean "in one's power or right of giving":

> The minor appointive offices which lie in his own gift. — James Bryce, *The American Commonwealth*, 1888.

I'd recognise that sense today, though consider it archaic. While I imagine the straight use of the word in that sense is largely obsolete today (though the OED doesn't list it as such).

Separately from that, the verb *give* acquired the sense of "yield" which give us yet another separate noun sense of *give*, the fact of yielding or the degree of doing so:

> They began levelling the pitch at 8 a.m. this morning and if the weather stays fine we should have a fair surface with some give in it. *The Times* (London) 1970.

This sense is still very much current.

The others not so much, and as a matter of current-day word choice I'd suggest *donation* or perhaps *giving*, but as a question about morphological nominalisation the answer is *give*, and also *gift*.

Answer (score 0):

> - [**"a gift"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gift) (noun) -  something that is given to another person or to a group or organization
> - [**"give"**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/give) (noun) - "the ability of a material to bend or stretch. e.g. "This fabric has a lot of give."
> - [**"giver"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giver) (noun) - " someone who gives something to another person."

Edit, after the OP edited.
**Giving** is the word for the act of giving.  "[**Giving**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=KDaLsmkiA1sC&q=giving+is&dq=giving+is&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=KgezVKGjJLiSsQTJ-YHgDw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA) is the best gift"

Comment: A gift is something that is given, not the act of giving.

Comment: 'Giving' is the proper noun, 'give' refers to 
1. Capacity or inclination to yield under pressure.
2. The quality or condition of resilience; springiness.

Comment: Strangely redolent of the 'comment' I posted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's in every dictionary. I started answering the moment the question was posted.  When I copy from comments, I give the credit.

Comment: @Yokel actually *gift* has indeed meant the act of giving from about as long back as it has meant the thing given, but has died out in that sense except in the derived idiom "in his gift" to mean "in his power to give".

Comment: @JonHanna Still in use in footballing terms _The goal, however, will haunt Manuel Pellegrini’s defensive unit for weeks, as Matija Nastasic didn’t realize Joe Hart had come out to help on a break, and he gifted Torres the winner._ http://prosoccertalk.nbcsports.com/2013/10/27/chelsea-2-1-manchester-city-horrific-defending-mistake-by-city-leaves-points-with-chelsea/

Comment: @Frank, that would be the (later) use of *gift* as a verb. The noun would be "his gift of the winner to Torres" though there one can't tell if *gift* means the goal or the act of giving it, which indeed is true of many uses of *donation* today, and one of those ambiguities where the two ways to interpret something amount to the same thing, and so aren't really ambiguous in practice.

Answer (score -2):

Use "giftation" or "giftion" as nominalizations of "to give" that exclude the gerund.

Comment: Can you add a sentence or two showing how these words would be used?